# How to get index position from a string in python without repetitive results

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, indexing

While in a for-loop of a `string`, I want to get the `index` position of that specific letter in that `string`, but if there are the same letters in that word, it doesn't work.

I looped through the letters in the `string` and got the `index` position of the letter (by using `.find()` or `.index()` ) for a `string` consisting of unique letters, but if the `string` contains the same letters, the index will only be the position of the first letter that appears in the `string`.

```py
indexList = [] #list of stored indexes
word = "grocery" #could be any string, just using "grocery" as an example
for letter in word:
  index = word.find(letter)
  indexList.append(index)

print (indexList)
```

```py
#Expected output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
#Actual output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6]
```

The 5 and 1 `index` positions have the same letters ("r"), so the `.find()` and `.index()` methods just add the 1 instead of the 5 because it is the first "r" in the `string`. I was wondering if there is any way to get the specified letter's position in the word. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: How about `enumerate`?

Comment: What you are describing is equivalent to `range(len(word))`, is there a use case for what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to save all the index positions to a ```list``` named ```positions``` with nested ```lists``` inside. Then I want to take a group of inputted words, and then take each of their letters, save them in the positions ```list``` in one of the nested ```lists```based on their index position, and then jumble them up and make a brand new word.

Comment: Can you add an example of that to the question or open a new question? You can just return `list(range(len(word)))` for the above

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, but I don't think I should add that to the question or open a new question since you have already answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` accepts two optional arguments: `start` (defaults to 0) and `end` (defaults to end of the string - that fits in your case). Use enumerate to include starting point:

```
for i, letter in enumerate(word):
    index = word.find(letter, i)
    indexList.append(index)
```